# Raspbian Stretch udisks2 automount

Tags: usb, raspbian-stretch, mount

I have installed udisks2 on a minimal Raspbian Strech image, but I can't find any doc to understand how to configure it in order to have USB automounted device.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have installed **udisks2** from the default Raspbian repository with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo apt install udisks2
```

For a first overview look at

```
rpi ~$ apt show udisks2
```

I would suggest for the first steps to start with `udisksctl`. You will also find the default documentation in `/usr/share/doc/udisks2` and within the man pages. There are three man pages installed:

- man udisks
- man udisksctl
- man udisksd

If it does not help enough then in `man udisks` you will find a list with 12 links to further sources.

Comment: Of course I went through all that documentation before posting the question. It did only increase my confusion.

Comment: No doc in the folder you pointed to. Only a generic README

Comment: @FabioMarzocca I have updated my answer. Please ask google for `udisks2 configuration`. I have found some sites providing information about it. Isn't automount working out of the box after installation? I would say just start with a configuration and if there are problems ask for help at https://unix.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @Ingo UDisks2 does not do automounting; You need wrappers to do that, if this page is to be believed: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/udisks
?